# what is the nature of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$3, 4, 10, 33, 136$

what will be next most appropriate value?
I tried finding any relation in the sequence but i couldn't.

$a.276 $

$b.539 $

$c.612 $

$d.685$

Comment: Is this just a puzzle or do you have some context you can provide?

Comment: I have got options with me. $a.276$ $b.539$ $c.612$ $d.685$

Comment: One option is $685$. $3, 3*1+1 = 4, 4*2 + 2 = 10, 10*3+3 = 33, 33*4+4 = 136, 136*5 + 5 = 685$... But such questions are nonsense as Qwirk's answer shows. I am voting to close a NARQ.

Comment: Is this some sort of homework?

Comment: Actually i had got a sample question paper saying, your actual entrance exam paper will be similar to it. So i am trying to solve it

Comment: @Moron- How did you get that relation in no time. Any easy way to solve such sequences?

Comment: @amul: I really don't know. There is no systematic method. Really, such questions are nonsense and solving this one likely won't help you solve other nonsense questions like this. It is unfortunate, but you have to guess what the idiot who wrote the question on the entrance test was thinking of...

Comment: @Moron-But even i can't help but try finding a relation in exam. I got two more questions like this in this paper!

Comment: @amul: Which test is this? I am curious.

Comment: @Moran-It's an entrance exam for my M.Sc.Actuaries.

Comment: How does something like this help with being an actuary? :o

Comment: I have no idea. But it will help me get into M.Sc.

Comment: @amul28: I think you should edit the question to include the list of optins. Just on example of another possibility: Noticing that $3.10+3=33$ and $4.33+4=136$ would suggest $a_{n+1}=a_{n-2}+a_{n-2}.a_n$.
This would lead to $10.136+10=1370$; which is not in your list of options.

Comment: yes. But it takes time finding all such possibilities.

Comment: I agree that questions like this can be frustrating, especially when multiple answers might fit, but I don't agree that they're completely worthless. I think the ability to look at arbitrary data, see patterns, find possible relationships, and then identify the most likely relationship is a critical skill for a mathematician to have. The question isn't "what was the exam writer thinking when he wrote this?", it's "what's the simplest relationship you can find between these numbers?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with all the complaints about this sort of problem, but still.... There are some techniques which work from time to time.

Try taking differences: $4-3=1$, $10-4=6$, $33-10=23$, $136-33=103$, so now we have to explain the sequence $1,6,23,103,\dots$. Hmm, that doesn't seem very helpful.

OK, subtraction didn't work, try division: $4\div3=1r1$, $10\div4=2r2$, $33\div10=3r3$, $136\div33=4r4$ - hey, that looks much better! (When I write $arb$, I mean quotient $a$, remainder $b$.)

Comment: seems very clear for me.

Comment: Wow! I never knew division could be applied. I always used subtraction. +1 for *arb* notation. Its really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I must say, I have always disliked 'find the next term in the series question'. For any sequence, it is easy to produce *any* number next (e.g. for a sequence of $n$ terms, pick the $n+1$ number and then fit a polynomial to those $n+1$ terms).

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C4%2C10%2C33%2C136&language=english&go=Search) does not give anything useful for your sequence - how has it arisen?

**Edit**: For this question, as Moron has shown, the likely answer is 685, based on the sequence $3,3\times 1 + 1 = 4, 4 \times 2 + 2 = 10, 10 \times 3 + 3 = 33, 33 \times 4 + 4 = 136,$$136 \times 5 + 5 = 685$ . But in general knowing how to find the pattern in *this* sequence, will not help (much) in finding patterns in similar sequences.